# Unable to subtract a bordered, not closed path from an oval shape in Sketch

Tags: vector, path, sketch-app

I've recently learnt how to work with vectors; I have drawn an oval and a line. I want to merge subtract the path from the oval now, but it looks like I can't do it.

It looks like I have to close the path in some way, but then it won't look as I want it to look.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Layer > Convert to Outlines**

Boolean operations work on paths, not strokes (or effects etc). You need to convert your stroke to outlines so that you are working exclusively with paths.